# Add Values to JavaScript object in Array with Anonymous Function

Tags: javascript

I'm using [Filepicker.io](https://www.inkfilepicker.com/) to store images. I'm trying to get the image's metadata using their `filepicker.stat()` function. However, while it allows me to work with the metadata internally like so:

```
filepicker.stat(InkBlobs[i], { width: true, height: true }, function(metadata){ console.log(JSON.stringify(metadata)) });
```

I can't get the metadata out of that anonymous function. What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < InkBlobs.length; i++)
{
    filepicker.stat(InkBlobs[i], { width: true, height: true }, function(metadata){ InkBlobs[i].add(JSON.stringify(metadata)); });
}
```

This obviously doesn't work (the `InkBlobs[i].add( ... )`) part, so how can I capture that metadata and include it with the other data located in the array? The array contents can each be `JSON.stringify()`'d.

Answer (score 1):

First, I assume that the callback receives `metadata` as an argument; that's missing from the code in the question, but I will assume that below.

You can do basically what you wrote, you just have to manage `i` slightly differently and have a place to store it. As this is JavaScript, you can just add your own property to the `InkBlob` instances, but that's typically a bit dangerous (in case you conflict with something non-public, or they add something similar to the objects in the next release, etc.).

First let's deal with `i`:

```
for(i = 0; i < InkBlobs.length; i++)
{
    filepicker.stat(InkBlobs[i], { width: true, height: true }, makeCallback(i));
}
function makeCallback(index) {
    return function(metadata){
        InkBlobs[index].add(JSON.stringify(metadata));
        // This bit ^^ is still theoretical
    };
}
```

Now, instead of closing over `i`, our callback closes over `index`, which is the argument we passed to `makeCallback` when we called it in the loop. Where `i` changes before the callback occurs, `index` does not.

You can also use ES5's `bind` if the `this` that the callback sees doesn't have to be controlled by `stat`:

```
for(i = 0; i < InkBlobs.length; i++)
{
    filepicker.stat(InkBlobs[i], { width: true, height: true }, function(index, metadata){
        InkBlobs[index].add(JSON.stringify(metadata));
        // This bit ^^ is still theoretical
    }.bind(null, i));
}
```

Note that the argument `i` we pass `bind` shows up in front of any supplied by `stat` (the first argument to `bind`, `null` in my example, is what sets `this` during the callback).

I'll use `bind` from here on out because it's more concise.

Now we have to store the metadata with the inkblobs. Here's one way:

```
var data = [];
var count = 0;
for(i = 0; i < InkBlobs.length; i++)
{
    filepicker.stat(InkBlobs[i], { width: true, height: true }, function(index, metadata){
        data[index] = {
            blob:     InkBlobs[index],
            metadata: metadata // No reason to stringify it that I know of, but you could
        };
        ++count;
        if (count === InkBlobs.length) {
            useTheNewArray();
        }
    }.bind(null, i));
}
```

Note that we wait to call `useTheNewArray` until we've seen the callback for all blobs. Also note that we don't just `push` to the new array, because they could arrive out of order (in theory). Of course, if the order doesn't matter, `push` away and you don't need the `count` variable anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response! Just to clarify, where you call `useTheNewArray();`, do you mean a direct copy over the previous InkBlobs array?

Comment: Also, if I'm not using the `bind()` method, wouldn't I also have to pass the metadata into `makeCallback()`?

Comment: For some reason or another, this isn't actually working for me. I tried both with the `bind()` and without (the former method and the latter) and the data array just stays empty. I guess it could be with however I'm trying to `useNewArray()`, but I'm not really sure what else you could do aside from straight up copying or returning the array.

Comment: @rar: By "use" I mean...use. Index into it and do things with the objects it has in it, *instead* of using `InkBlobs`. No, you don't have to pass `metadata` into `makeCallback` -- `makeCallback`'s job is to create function that `stat` will call with the `metadata` argument.

Comment: Ah okay. I found it confusing in that I don't actually USE the `InkBlobs` array until after the for loop is complete. I just wanted to modify the contents of each object by adding the metadata to each one before using it outside of the for loop.